# How to Run Copy List Item Workflow Across Whole List at Once

Tags: 2013, list, designer-workflow, workflow-activity

I want to archive a large list (list 1), therefore i saved template of that list without content and renamed it (list 2) and created brand new empty list off that template. Now i am using if statement to compare status of the list item(list 1) as closed. if the condition is met i am copying list item into List 2 and pausing the workflow for 1 minute and delete that item of the list 1.

i have set the workflow to fire off manually.

I have about 5000 items on the list, I cant sit all day and trigger workflow off each item manually. Is there a way i can use this workflow to go across all items on the list and do its job automatically.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can usePowerShell to run workflow on all items. The Workflow will not start instantly (as opposed to triggering through the UI) but in maximum 5 minutes because it's started through the SharePoint Timer Service.

```
# URL of the Site
$web = Get-SPWeb -Identity "https://sharepointsrv/site1"

$manager = $web.Site.WorkFlowManager

# Name of the list
$list = $web.Lists["Shared Documents"]

# Name of the Workflow
$assoc = $list.WorkflowAssociations.GetAssociationByName("On Item Created","en-US")

$data = $assoc.AssociationData
$items = $list.Items
foreach($item in $items)
 {
 $wf = $manager.StartWorkFlow($item,$assoc,$data,$true)
 }

$manager.Dispose()
$web.Dispose()
```

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/dffdceab-f2fe-4886-8e2a-ea26cf08c78a/how-to-start-a-speific-workflow-programatically-in-sharepoint-2010-via-powershell

http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Start-a-Workflow-on-120bffe5

Comment: thank you for your response, What items needs to be changed in the powershell for my workflow lets call it( Aanchal) to trigger automatically.

Comment: I am not able to understand your query.

Comment: What do i need to change in above powershell for it to work on my case.

Comment: Changr site url, document library name and workflow name. Do test it on dev server before running this on prod

Comment: Do i need to change the settings to actual workflow which is currently set to trigger manually?

Comment: No you dont need to change anything

Comment: Sure i will try that in dev and let you know if that works, thanks again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17376/discussion-between-allegro-octopus-and-aanchal).

Comment: This is what i got
 Exception calling "StartWorkflow" with "4" argument(s): "" 
At \\archive.ps1:17 char:2 
+ $wf = $manager.StartWorkFlow($item,$assoc,$data,$true) 
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
+ CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException 
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : SPException

Comment: try this http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/23850.sharepoint-2013-workflow-management-starting-a-workflow-using-powershell.aspx